# Facebook story posting issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am setting up for posting story on facebook but I am getting following alert:

> You, or this app's Open Graph Test User, must have published this action at least once.

I am getting `id` in the response but when I am clicking on that I am redirecting to "*Page not found*".

Here is my code :

```
FB.api(
   'me/objects/appnamespace:objecttype',
   'post',
   {
      object :{
         app_id: myappId,
         objectype: myurl,
         title: "Sample Organization",
         image: mylogo,
         description: ""
      }
   },
   function(response) {
      if (!response) {
         alert('Error occurred.');
      } else if (response.error) {
         document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
                          'Error: ' + response.error.message;
      } else {
         document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
                     '<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/me/activity/' +
                     response.id + '\">' +
                     'Story created.  ID is ' +
                     response.id + '</a>';
      }
  }
);
```